# Can I intercept an incoming request in Express.js before it's handled?

Tags: json, node.js, validation, express

I'm running Node.js with Express.js and everything works perfectly until someone sends invalid JSON with content-type text/json and then my server responds with a 400.

Now, I realize this is "correct" but I'd like to intercept the incoming data and see if I can fix the data by replacing all the new lines (\n \r) with the string representations thereof ("\n", "\r") because that appears to be the problem with the incoming request. Specifically, the json has instances that look like

```
{"foo":"bar
and so forth"}
```

Where the line breaks are some combination of \n and \r.

I'm not seeing where I can look-at/massage the incoming request data before it gets bounced as a 400.

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to do it before your bodyparser middleware.

Comment: @KevinB, any chance you have a link to an example of how that's done?

Comment: Nope, but it's relatively simple. `app.use(function () {... fix it here ...});`

Comment: @KevinB, so I do this before the app.use(BodyParser.json()) line, right? and then what is the *it that I'm fixing?

Comment: yes. the invalid json of course. but you first have to determine whether or not it is invalid.

Comment: @KevinB, meaning, what property of request am I handling here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely what middleware is all about.  Just insert a middleware handler as the very first handler (before anything else that might look at the request data such as `app.use(BodyParser.json())`) and it gets first crack at every request and it can modify the request object as it wants to before any of your other handlers see the data.

```
// make this the first request handler for Express
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // examine req here and make any changes as desired

    // when done, call next()
    next();
});
```

If it's a GET request, the data is all there.  If it's a POST request, you will you have to actually read the request stream to get the data before you can process it.  This probably means you have to actually replace `bodyParser.json()` with your own unless you replace the request stream with a new stream.

Comment: so... what property of req do I noodle with? I'm going to run a regex on it to strip out the new lines...

Comment: @GeniaS. - What type of request are you trying to fix?  Is it a POST?  That determines where the data is in the reqest.

Comment: @GeniaS. - A POST complicates it a bit.  You have to actually ready the request stream to get the content since the content of a POST comes in the stream.  I wonder if you might have better luck just modifying the `BodyParser.json()` code to tolerate/fix your issues.  You can see that code here: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js.  For reference, the code it uses to read the stream is here: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/read.js